# Why doesn't Kotlin use static inner class to implement singleton with the "object" keyword?

Tags: kotlin, singleton

Here is a class A that is decorated with the "object" keyword:

```kotlin
object A {
}
```

After decompiling it into Java code, it was found that it is initialized through a static code block:

```java
public final class A {
   public static final A INSTANCE;

   private A() {
   }

   static {
      A var0 = new A();
      INSTANCE = var0;
   }
}
```

I'm curious why Kotlin doesn't use static inner class to implement singleton, just like this:

```java
public final class A {
    public A getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private A() {
    }

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final A INSTANCE = new A();
    }
}
```

Then, when using a variable "b" in class A, add "getInstance()" method between A and getB():

```java
public static final void main() {
    A.getInstance().getB();
}
```

This singleton pattern supports lazy loading, which can avoid memory waste. Why doesn't Kotlin use this approach to implement the "object" keyword?

Comment: What use case(s) do you imagine lazily instantiating the singleton would be beneficial? That's not an admonishment, I'm genuinely curious. In my mind, if you reference an `object` then you are pretty much guaranteed to be calling a function on it or referencing a member variable, both of which will require the instance to exist anyway, so you might as well do the simpler implementation and create the instance eagerly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current behaviour is basically the same as what you are proposing, assuming you don't have anything `@JvmStatic`/`@JvmField` in the object.

All the initialisation is done in the [static initialiser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7), which

> is executed when the class is *initialized*

And a class `T` is [initialised](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1),

> immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - `T` is a class and an instance of `T` is created.
> - A static method declared by `T` is invoked.
> - A static field declared by `T` is assigned.
> - A static field declared by `T` is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

So no object is created before you access the `INSTANCE` static field, where all the members of the kotlin `object` reside. That's basically what your `getInstance` is trying to achieve, isn't it? You are kind of reinventing the wheel by creating your own `getInstance`.

One may even argue that your `LazyHolder` is one extra class that needs loading, and thus is worse than the current implementation in this respect.

Things get more complicated when you introduce `@JvmStatic`/`@JvmField`, both of which allows you to access the kotlin properties without going through `INSTANCE`.

```
object O {
    @JvmStatic
    val static = 0
    val notStatic = 1
}
```

In this case, an object will be created if you just accessed `O.static`, and your proposed solution indeed solves that problem.

However, your proposed solution also makes the semantics of `init` blocks in objects very confusing - when is the code inside `init` blocks executed?

Allow me to use a rather contrived example:

```
object O {
    @JvmStatic
    val static: Int
    val notStatic: Int

    init {
        timeConsumingSideEffect()
        val x = iDontWantToRunThisTwice()
        static = timeConsumingComputation(x)
        notStatic = timeConsumingComputation(x)
    }
}
```

Should they be put inside the static initialiser of `O`, or `LazyHolder`?

If they are put inside the static initialiser of `O`, then it's not lazy anymore. As soon as you access `O.static`, everything is run, just like the current implementation.

If they are put inside the static initialiser of `LazyHolder`, then it is possible for other code to get an uninitialised value by accessing `O.static`.

While it may be possible to separate out the code in the `init` block responsible for initialising `@JvmStatic` properties vs those that initialise regular properties using some clever data flow analysis, it is still unclear when `timeConsumingSideEffect()` should run.

Language design is difficult!

Comment: The thing is, looking at the byte-code with `javap`, the `notStatic` property is still compiled to a `static` field, yet the associated `getNotStatic()` method will be an _instance_ method. Though that doesn't really affect anything regarding lazy vs. eager; I just find it strange.

Comment: Maybe since `init{}` is compiled into `static{}` in Java, it is convenient to compile `notStatic` into a static variable for initialization in `init{}`.@Slaw

Comment: @sulv True. Though if there were no `JvmStatic`s, compiling `init` into the *instance* constructor could also work (making all the properties instance fields too). Adding an extra case to handle this though, is indeed less convenient and adds complexity.

Comment: Although `static` and `notStatic` are initialized in `init{}`, no instance of class O has been created. In addition, I think that properties and methods with `@JvmField` or `@JvmStatic` annotations can be initialized in the `init{}` of class O, and other properties and methods can be initialized in `LazyHolder`. Is this solution feasible?@Sweeper

Comment: @sulv Yeah, that is what the very last paragraph in my answer was referring to. As I said, separating out those properties could be a complicated data flow analysis process, and may require even more complex code transformations. It would be much easier, and a lot less costly, to design it so that everything is shoved in the static initialiser. Just like [Eric Lippert's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585) said, "A development team is never required to provide a good reason for not doing work and not spending money"